# Initialize Destructuring props if null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I would like to initialize my variable to [] if it's null or non-existant.

Here my code:

```
  const {
columnDates = [],
rowTitles = [],
last3MonthComparisonDirections = [],
last3MonthComparisonMeanings = [],
last3MonthComparisonValues = [],
last3MonthValues = [],
last12MonthValues = [],
lastMonthComparisonDirections = [],
lastMonthComparisonMeanings = [],
lastMonthComparisonValues = [],
lastMonthValues = [],
yearToDateValues = [],
emphasisRow = [],
  } = table;
```

The problem right now is if `columnDates` in table is null, then my variable columnDates is null. I would like it initialize it at [] instead of null if it's null.

Any suggestion ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer Default values are applied for **undefined** props, but null is a value for an already defined prop, so you need to do these checks manually,

In addition to the suggested approaches, I'd suggest one more approach, to use a **Proxy**

```js
const table = {
  columnDates: null,
  rowTitles: [1,2,3],
  last3MonthComparisonDirections: [],
  last3MonthComparisonMeanings: null,
  yearToDateValues: ['a,','b','c'],
  emphasisRow: null
}; 

var proxyObj = new Proxy(table, {
  get: (target, prop) => target[prop] === null ? undefined : target[prop]
});

const {
  columnDates = [],
  rowTitles = [],
  last3MonthComparisonDirections = [],
  last3MonthComparisonMeanings = [],
  last3MonthComparisonValues = [],
  last3MonthValues = [],
  last12MonthValues = [],
  lastMonthComparisonDirections = [],
  lastMonthComparisonMeanings = [],
  lastMonthComparisonValues = [],
  lastMonthValues = [],
  yearToDateValues = [],
  emphasisRow = [],
 } = proxyObj;

console.log(columnDates); // []
console.log(rowTitles); // [1,2,3]
console.log(lastMonthValues); // []
console.log(last3MonthComparisonDirections); // []
```

You don't want to use default values? you can return `[]` for undefined props too:

```js
const table = {
  columnDates: null,
  rowTitles: [1,2,3],
  last3MonthComparisonDirections: [],
  last3MonthComparisonMeanings: null,
  yearToDateValues: ['a,','b','c'],
  emphasisRow: null
}; 

var proxyObj = new Proxy(table, {
  get: (target, prop) => target[prop] || []
});

const {
  columnDates,
  rowTitles,
  last3MonthComparisonDirections,
  last3MonthComparisonMeanings,
  last3MonthComparisonValues,
  last3MonthValues,
  last12MonthValues,
  lastMonthComparisonDirections,
  lastMonthComparisonMeanings,
  lastMonthComparisonValues,
  lastMonthValues,
  yearToDateValues,
  emphasisRow,
 } = proxyObj;

console.log(columnDates); // []
console.log(rowTitles); // [1,2,3]
console.log(lastMonthValues); // []
console.log(last3MonthComparisonDirections); // []
```

Also, you can check for specific allowed or expected keys, so not all undefined props will return `[]`:

```js
const table = {
  columnDates: null,
  rowTitles: [1,2,3],
  last3MonthComparisonDirections: [],
  last3MonthComparisonMeanings: null,
  yearToDateValues: ['a,','b','c'],
  emphasisRow: null
}; 

// Define possible allowed props, 
const possibleProps = [
  'columnDates',
  'rowTitles',
  'last3MonthComparisonDirections',
  'last3MonthComparisonMeanings',
  'last3MonthComparisonValues',
  'last3MonthValues',
  'last12MonthValues',
  'lastMonthComparisonDirections',
  'lastMonthComparisonMeanings',
  'lastMonthComparisonValues',
  'lastMonthValues',
  'yearToDateValues',
  'emphasisRow'
 ];

var proxyObj = new Proxy(table, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    if (possibleProps.includes(prop)) {
      return target[prop] || [];
    }
    
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
});

const {
  columnDates,
  rowTitles,
  last3MonthComparisonDirections,
  last3MonthComparisonMeanings,
  last3MonthComparisonValues,
  last3MonthValues,
  last12MonthValues,
  lastMonthComparisonDirections,
  lastMonthComparisonMeanings,
  lastMonthComparisonValues,
  lastMonthValues,
  yearToDateValues,
  emphasisRow,
 } = proxyObj;

console.log(columnDates); // []
console.log(rowTitles); // [1,2,3]
console.log(lastMonthValues); // []
console.log(last3MonthComparisonDirections); // []
```

Answer (score 2):

The default value will only be used if the value being destructured is `undefined`. Changing that isn't something you can do. You have a few options:

1. Don't use destructuring, and instead use the newer [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`):

   ```js
   const columnDates = table.columnDates ?? []; // default if columnDates is `null` or `undefined`
   ... continue for others ...
   ```

If you're only having this problem with `columnDates`, then perform the above for `columnDates` and then use destructuring for the other properties. Otherwise, if all values could be `null`, then perform the above for each property.

2. Map the `null` values to `undefined` so you take the default values for `null` values:

   ```js
   const {
     columnDates = [], 
     rowTitles = [], 
     ... etc ...
   } = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(table).map(
     ([key, val]) => [key, val === null ? undefined : val]
   ));
   ```

The above maps over the entire `table` object's values and builds a new object for you with the previous `null` values now as `undefined`.

3. Instead of mapping the entire object, you could instead create an array of string properties you want to extract,  and map those from the object:

   ```js
   const keys = ["columnDates", "rowTitles", ...];
   const desiredKeys = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(
     key => [key, table[key] == null ? [] : table[key]]
   ));
   ```

The above uses `==` to check if `table[key]` is equal to `null` **or** `undefined`, and if it is, it will default the value to an empty `[]` array. If you only want this behaviour for `null`, then use strict equality `===` instead.